# Is it possible for two Minecraft players to use the same map, if they are in different networks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Imagine player 1 and player 2 want to play the [Funlands 3](http://www.minecraftmaps.com/creation-maps/funland-3/viewdownload) map (so that both of them are in that map). They are located in different networks (not on the same LAN).

Is it possible to set up Minecraft so that both players can play in the same map?

If yes, what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions; one is to setup your own server (easy getting started tutorial [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)), or you could use a service like [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/CA-EN/products/hamachi/default.aspx) to create a private virtual network between two or more parties (I do believe it is free for personal use, download [here](https://secure.logmein.com/CA-EN/products/hamachi/download.aspx)).

For a really easy setup, I would chose Hamachi. You don't have to fiddle around with any server stuff and you can connect to the other player like you were playing on LAN.